# Type-checking a TypeScript monorepo

Tags: typescript

### Context

I work on a TypeScript monorepo set up with [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/workspaces). The TypeScript files are located in various places:

- project source files (`packages/*/src/**/*.ts`);
- config files at the root of the repo (`*.ts`);
- config files at the root of project folders (`packages/*/*.ts`);
- Cypress specs and Cypress config files (`cypress/**/*.ts`).

When I open any one of those files in **VS Code**, I want the TypeScript language server to **type-check the file** so VS Code can underline problems in the editor.

To achieve this, I have a root `tsconfig.json` file that configures strict type-checking for all TS files in the monorepo (`node_modules` excluded, of course). It looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "strict": true,
     "noEmit": true,
     ... // lot more options
  }
}
```

In order for VS Code to correctly type-check source files in project folders, notably by making sure that **only the relevant `@types` packages are loaded for each project**, I place a `tsconfig.json` file inside each project folder that extends the monorepo's root `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json"
}
```

> The `tsconfig.json` file in the `cypress` folder has a few more things in it but is conceptually the same.

### Problem

At this point, the monorepo is configured to be type-checked in VS Code. I can open any `.ts` file, and the language server correctly reports any typing problems.

Now I need to be able to **type-check the entire monorepo from the command line**. I need:

1. *all* the TS files listed at the start to be type-checked;
2. *only* the TS files listed at the start to be type-checked;
3. type-checking isolation between projects to be maintained (i.e. when checking a source file located in the `foo` project, only the `@type` packages and type definitions of packages listed in `packages/foo/package.json` and installed under `packages/foo/node_modules` must be included);
4. the same files to not be type-checked multiple times (to save time and so the same typing error doesn't get reported twice.

#### `tsc --project tsconfig.json`

1. **PASS**: the root `tsconfig` includes all `.ts` files in the repo except those under `node_modules`.
2. **FAIL**: `.ts` files located inside output folders (`dist`, `build`, `out`, etc.) are also type-checked.
3. **FAIL**: all `@type` packages and type definitions get included, which breaks isolation between projects and leads to conflicts for global types (e.g. Cypress vs Jest), making type-checking unreliable.
4. **PASS**: `tsc` runs only once, so no problem here.

#### `tsc --project tsconfig.check.json`

With `tsconfig.check.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["*.ts", "packages/*/*.ts, "packages/*/src/**/*.ts", ...]
}
```

1. **PASS**
2. **PASS**: annoying and easy to forget to keep in sync, but works
3. **FAIL**: still no isolation
4. **PASS**

#### `tsc -p tsconfig.check.json && tsc -p packages/foo/tsconfig.json && ...`

With the root `tsconfig.check.json` including `["*.ts"]`, and the projects' `tsconfig.json` modified to include `["*.ts", "src/**/*.ts"]`.

> Each project's `tsc` command can be put in an NPM script to take advantage of pnpm's ability to [run scripts recursively](https://pnpm.io/cli/run#--recursive--r).

1. **PASS**
2. **PASS**: output folders are not included.
3. **PASS**: `tsconfig.check.json` doesn't include project files and the projects' `tsconfig.json` files are mutually exclusive (i.e. they don't include each others' files).
4. **FAIL**: if project `foo` imports files from project `bar`, and `tsc` runs for both `foo` and `bar`, then the imported files are type-checked twice; and if `tsc` runs only on `foo` and not on `bar`, files in `bar` that are *not* imported by `foo` are not type-checked (e.g. test files).

#### TypeScript project references

Unless I'm mistaken, `tsc --build --noEmit` is [not yet supported](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53979).

### What I'm after...

- A way to run `tsc` once from the root of the monorepo while also taking into account nested `tsconfig.json` files, similarly to VS Code's language server?
- A tool that can perform type-checking like `tsc` but without the limitation I'm describing?
- A way to structure my `tsconfig` files to pass all four requirements above, and without losing type-checking in the IDE?
- A script that makes use of the TypeScript Compiler API somehow?
- ...?

Comment: Nope! I've opted for the third solution (i.e. running `tsc` in each project), so I end up type-checking a bunch of stuff multiple times...